# How do I use viewbag object and modify with onclick?

Tags: c#, .net, razor, knockout.js

I have a dropdown list of states with options loaded from a ViewBag. Knockout is replacing the ViewBag object with nothing. How do I 
A. Pass the (IEnumerable)ViewBag.States to knockout and 
B. Modify the drop down after an onclick event to show the modified (IEnumerable) of states.

This is where I am stuck... Thanks in advance!

**CSHTML**

```
@(Html.DropDownList("State", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.States, "Any", new { @class = "fieldState", data_bind = "options: $root.setStates, optionsText: 'st', value: 'fullName'" }))
```

**Javascript triggered from an onclick event**

```
pageViewModel.setDropdown().setStates.push(new SetDropdown());
```

**JS file**

```
self.setDropdown = ko.observable(new SetDropdown());

function SetDropdown(stateIS02, longName) {
    var self = this;

    self.setStates = ko.observableArray();

    this.st = stateIS02;
    this.name = longName;
}
```

I am now out of ideas...

Comment: You dont mix server side MVC and client side MVVM

Answer (score 3):

```
<p>
    State:
    <select data-bind="options: $root.states, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue : 'Id', value: selectedState, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
    <br />Selected State value:
    <span data-bind="text: selectedState"></span>
</p> 
<script>
    var stateData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.States));  
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Constructor for an object with two properties
    var State = function (id, name) {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    };
    var initialState = new Array();
    if (stateData.length > 0) {        
        for (var k = 0; k < stateData.length; k++) {
            initialState.push(new State(stateData[k].Value, stateData[k].Text));
        }
    }
    var viewModel = {
        states: ko.observableArray(initialState),
        selectedState: ko.observable() // Nothing selected by default
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

Comment: This is a good solution which works but I came up with the answer after burning the night oil and coming in.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research I figured it out!

I have the data-bind attribute set on the click event on the javascript side. I am also now using the push function in a loop to set the states.

```
pageViewModel.setStates.push({ shortState : "VA", fullName: "Virginia"}); //will be in a loop
$("#State").attr('data-bind', "options: $root.setStates, optionsText: function(item) { return item.shortState; }, value: function(item){ return item.fullName;}");
ko.applyBindings(pageViewModel);
```